# How to commit the .svn folder to a Mercurial repository?

Tags: svn, mercurial, directory, commit

I want to commit the `.svn` folder, of each code folder, to the Hg repository. The problem is that many `.svn` subfolders are empty and, because of that, can't be committed to the mercurial repository.

One solution I found is to add an empty file to each of those folders, but this is cumbersome. Isn't there an easier way?

Comment: Why do you need the .svn folder under source control?

Comment: @jgifford We have to commit to the SVN repository eventually, but we use Mercurial daily

Comment: @Jader, we're in a similar situation as you as we have to use CVS by corporate standards, but are using Git for our sanity. We don't check in the CVS folders. We work in our git repo/directory and periodically do code pulls into a cloned local repository/directory that contains our CVS checkout. We then commit to CVS from that CVS checkout folder.

Comment: Just note that the files in the .svn folders are not possible to merge. Parallel commits to the Subversion repository will fail. Are you *sure* this is how you want to do it?

Comment: @Yads it worked. I will have to click more but that's the only way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to use hg on top of a svn repo, you can try the [hgsubversion extension](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/wiki/Home). Hgsubversion gives mercurial the ability to talk to svn servers like a svn client.

OTOH if you insist to have .svn folders everywhere, you can use [hgsvn](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/hgsvn/) to manage your parallel hg and svn repo checkout. But hgsvn has the drawback that it does no automatic rebase for stuff which gets back into svn, so when you have had to merge (in terms of a mercurial merge) the svn history with your local history, you can't export every local commit, only the merge commit (there is the way to export every commit even when there is a merge, but the first local commit will undo the recent svn history, and the merge commit will redo it, which causes a defect svn history).

More about different svn<->hg workflows are on the [WorkingWithSubversion](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WorkingWithSubversion) wiki page.

Comment: I couldn't use hgsubversion since my SVN repository requires that (pre-commit hook) every new file should have the `svn:needs-lock` property

Answer (score 4):

You need to add an empty file for each.  You could do that quickly with:

```
for thedir in $(find /path/to/repo -type -d -name .svn) ; do
  touch $thedir/emptyfile
  hg add $thedir/emptyfile
done
```

Comment: great script! maybe someone could write one for windows as well

Comment: I think windows scripts are called interns. ;)